# AWS IAM Role not being assumed - EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

My setup is as follows:

```
iam user --> iam user group --> assume role group policy --> eks cluster role --> eks role bindings
```

So, I have an assume role policy:

```
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          AWS = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
        }
      },
    ]
```

Then I have a user group, with the following group policy:

```
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "sts:AssumeRole",
        ]
        Sid = "AllowAssumeOrganizationAccountRole"
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Resource = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/ro-k8s-role"
      },
    ]
```

I then have the following cluster role for EKS:

```
  rule {
    api_groups     = ["apps", "batch", "extensions"]
    resources      = ["pods", "deployments", "statefulsets", "events", "services", "pods/log", "pods/portforward"]
    verbs          = ["get", "list", "watch", "describe"]
  }
```

And then a bunch of role bindings which are used for a list of namespaces:

```
  metadata {
    name      = "k8s-ro-${each.value}"
    namespace = each.value
  }
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "Role"
    name      = "k8s-ro"
  }
  subject {
    kind      = "User"
    name      = "k8s-user"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
```

If I then use the profile of a user in the group, and check the caller-identity...

```
{
    "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Account": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:user/test-user"
}
```

I would expect to see the assume role here, right? Which explains why I can't view anything running on the cluster.

Comment: How are you doing the assume role? How are you defining the role in the aws_auth configmap?

Comment: I realise what I’ve done wrong here I think. I didn’t actually add anything AWS config to do the assume role! Doh! Will update when at my desk and if it works resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll close this as the initial problem is resolved. I hadn't properly configured the AWS Profiles to automatically handle the assume role. Which having done has resolved this issue.

~/.aws/config

```
[profile test]
cli_pager =
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/k8s-role
source_profile = test
region = eu-west-1
```

~/.aws/credentials

```
[test]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```